# ¿Cómo pasar valores de un button con addEventListener y a su vez a la function() final dentro de otra función?

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

No me está reconociendo el `getElementById` del botton dentro de `ShowCart();`.

Lo importante de todo es pasar el valor del `value` button **sin utilizar el evento "OnClick"** ya que es una **extensión de Chrome** y no es posible utilizarlo. Unicamente puedo utilizar addEventListener.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo pasar valores de un `button` con `addEventListener` y a su vez a la `function() final` dentro de otra función?**

Este es mi código:

```
// Resultado: si existe : undefined
showCart();

var BORRAR = document.getElementById("borrar_producto");

if (BORRAR) {
    alert("si existe: " + this.value);
    BORRAR.addEventListener("click", borrar_item);
} else {
   alert("NO EXISTE")
}

function borrar_item (index) {
    alert(index); 
}         

function showCart() {
    $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#cartBody").empty();
    for (var i in cart) {
        var item = cart[i];
        var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
                     item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>"
                     + item.Qty * item.Price + "</td><td>"
                     + "<button id='borrar_producto' value="+i+">Borrar</button></td></tr>";
        $("#cartBody").append(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unicamente me esta reconociendo el primer ID del bucle de botones de mi cesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo tienes que cambiar un par de cosas para que te funcione:

1. No pongas los paréntesis en la función dentro del `addEventListener`, o lo que estarás haciendo es llamarla. En su lugar, simplemente pon el nombre para que se asocie al evento `click`:

   ```
   BORRAR_BOTON.addEventListener("click", borrar_item);
   ```
2. Ahora en `borrar_item` ya no estás pasando ningún parámetro, puedes acceder al objeto asociado usando `this`. Por lo tanto, para leer el valor tendrás que hacer algo como:

   ```
   this.value
   ```

Y con eso ya estaría. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
var BORRAR_BOTON = document.getElementById("borrar_producto");
BORRAR_BOTON.addEventListener("click", borrar_item);

function borrar_item(){
  alert(this.value); 
}
```

```html
<button id='borrar_producto' value="valorx">Borrar</button>
```

Comment: Si en realidad la respuesta es correcta. El punto que se me paso agregar es que el boton de borrar lo tengo dentro de la funcion showCart(); y eso hace que me genere problemas de reconocimiento del elementoByid. GRACIAS!  Ya lo modifique en la pregunta original.